# 56 plate fiat punto grande main beam won't work but hight beam will

Tags: headlight, wiring, fuse

Hi I don't no if I will get any advice I got a car to mess about with just to learn about cars a bit more and the main beam will not work but the high beam does I have checked all the fuses and none of them have blown and I've looked at the wiring and can't see no splits or anything, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you checked the bulbs? Also the fuses can be broken not blown so it still looks good - try swapping fir a new one.

Comment: Yes I have swapped the bulbs for new ones to rule that out and still nothing, I'm not to sure the location of the correct fuse to replace as I can't find anything online I took them all out 1 by 1 and checked there still connected in the middle and none of them were